# Randomized File (Stream) From List of Checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, resources, embedded-resource, accessor

So this is a two part question.  Moving question #2 to the top since #1 has been answered.

*Question #2 - What would be an ideal method to use checkboxes from the initial instance of Form1 (that is sadly unnamed) to set what objects are allowed.  I was thinking perhaps I could have a hidden form that holds variables, and use a set accessor called from Form1 on change to the checkboxes and updates the list or dictionary I call in my above mentioned function?*

The first is, I have multiple images - two currently but more to come - and want to randomly use one of those each time the function is called.  Currently I'm doing this:

```
            System.IO.Stream file;

            Random rnd = new Random(int.Parse(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
            int a = rnd.Next(0, 2);

            if (a == 0)  {file = thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("QATestFileGenTools.checkFront1.bmp");}
            else if (a == 1)  {file = thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("QATestFileGenTools.checkFront2.bmp");}
            else {file = thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("QATestFileGenTools.checkFront2.bmp");}
```

The plan was the final else was to use that image as default  in the future.  As seen, each image will be a resource embedded in the executable.  I'd like to clean this up, possibly using a dictionary or list, where I randomly get a number between `0` and `list.size-1` and then set the `file` equal to that.

*Question #1 - How can I make a list or dictionary of resource pointers and then set `file` to be that resource that time?*

Now, currently I cannot use my checkboxes.  I have two checkboxes on `Form1` to reflect each of the two current images.  Since there's no way to call `Form1.cbImage1.Checked` because the initial instance has no name/identifier, I was considering setting a global variable, which I am loathe to do.  I tried setting a get accessor, but of course that runs into the same issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You possibly don't want to get streams that you are not going to consume soon, so placing the stream itself in a dictionary may not be the best idea.  How about instead creating a dictionary of resource names, getting the resource name from the dictionary based on the random number, then opening the appropriate stream.

Comment: Sorry, yes - that's precisely what I want to do.  Though I've considered the other as well, I don't think it would improve performance much.  I imagine I will never have more than five or so images, though a single run of the application can require up to 1000 images easily (meaning each of the five will be utilized almost certainly). 

Would there be ANY speed benefit to having the entire stream in the dictionary vs having the name? I've had trouble pulling a name from a string and calling based on that - any tips? Is there a way to use an ACTUAL pointer to those values that already exist?

Comment: What about a public class somewhere else that has a set accessor which is called from the initial instance of Form1 anytime a checkbox value is modified?  I've not been able to create a functional get or set accessor, but I imagine that's primarily because I've been trying to `get` from the Form1 that has no instance name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question #1:

```
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dict.Add(0, "QATestFileGenTools.checkFront1.bmp");
        dict.Add(1,"QATestFileGenTools.checkFront2.bmp");
        dict.Add(2, "QATestFileGenTools.checkFront2.bmp");

        Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        int randomInt = rnd.Next(0, 2);

        string resourceName = dict[randomInt];
        System.IO.Stream file file = thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
```

**Edit:** changed the random seed to something simpler and probably equally effective.

Comment: Hah duh!  That makes complete sense.  Perhaps I was way overcomplicating it in my head.  Thanks Xavier!  That's perfect.  Now if I could just build that dictionary from data in the checkboxes and still have it readable from another class that was not part of Form1.

Comment: I am glad it works for you. Also: I usually use `DateTime.Now.Millisecond` as a seed for the `Random` class. I was surprised by the complicated seed shown in your code. And please don't forget to marked the question as "answered" if it was indeed the correct answer. Cheers.

Comment: Well, I'm still hoping for an answer for the other part - but I will mark for sure.  And yes, that's definitely overly complex for what I need here - I just grabbed it from another bit of code for the time being.

Comment: I edited the answer to replace the seed by a simpler one.

Comment: If you don't specify a seed, the current system time is used anyhow.

Comment: Never instantiate something that implements IDisposable (such as a stream) without a foolproof means to dispose of that object in a timely manner.  The `using` keyword is your friend here.

Comment: Yes, `using` will definitely be a heavy part of this.

Comment: @XavierPeña - it had been too long, there actually WAS a reason I used a more complex RNG seed in at least several places.  In some areas, a random number was being generated 8-14 times per ms, so the results were the same for groups of data.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, for question #2, I am creating a dictionary of objects (configuration data) along with calls to various worker classes.  This might be clumsy, but it's allowing me to send various data in a single variable, arrays, integers, booleans and strings.  So long as the code is commented well, it's easy enough to typecast them on the other side.